# Is it possible to prioritize every column in SQL ORDER BY or is it limited to the order you place them?

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, ssms

I'm trying to do a very specific ordering with a SQL server. I have tried two different queries, and they're close, but they create an issue that I can't completely fix.

It'll be easier if I show the results I want:

| ID | Ring_Size | W_Size | Purity | F_Size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D46320 | 16 | 3.4 | 38 | 94 |
| F15555 | 10 | 10.1 | 4 | 81 |
| B45555 | 10 | 14.01 | 4 | 83.1 |
| E64444 | 10 | 14.0 | 2 | 84.2 |
| E64444 | 10 | 14.81 | 2 | 84.2 |
| B45445 | 10 | 15.1 | 2 | 87.1 |
| B45475 | 10 | 15.1 | 4 | 87.1 |
| E66744 | 10 | 15.1 | 4 | 87.1 |

This focuses on ring size in descending order. Then it pairs w_size together in ascending order *while also keeping ID's together*.
Then, finally, when there are matches, it would order the matches by purity ascending.

I can only achieve all but one of these conditions. I keep trading something off.

I can achieve everything except the final ordering by ascending purity with this code:

```
SELECT 
    ID, Ring_Size, 
    RIGHT(Gspec, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(Gspec)) - 1) AS W_SIZE,
    LEFT(Gspec, CHARINDEX(' ', Gspec) - 1) AS Purity, F_Size 
FROM 
    JewelColl
ORDER BY 
    Ring_Size DESC, 
    RIGHT(Gspec, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(Gspec)) - 1) + ID,
    CAST(LEFT(Gspec, CHARINDEX(' ', Gspec) - 1) AS INT)
```

Which will result in:

| ID | Ring_Size | W_Size | Purity | F_Size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D46320 | 16 | 3.4 | 38 | 94 |
| F15555 | 10 | 10.1 | 4 | 81 |
| B45555 | 10 | 14.01 | 4 | 83.1 |
| E64444 | 10 | 14.0 | 2 | 84.2 |
| E64444 | 10 | 14.81 | 2 | 84.2 |
| B45445 | 10 | 15.1 | 4 | 87.1 |
| B45475 | 10 | 15.1 | 4 | 87.1 |
| E66744 | 10 | 15.1 | 2 | 87.1 |

You'll notice the last three rows for purity had the order changed to 4, 4, 2. Which is purity desc.

I can fix that with another query, but it no longer keeps ID's together:

```
SELECT 
    ID, Ring_Size, 
    RIGHT(Gspec, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(Gspec)) - 1) AS W_SIZE,
    LEFT(Gspec, CHARINDEX(' ', Gspec) - 1) AS Purity, F_Size 
FROM 
    JewelColl
ORDER BY 
    Ring_Size DESC, 
    RIGHT(Gspec, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(Gspec)) - 1),
    CAST(LEFT(Gspec, CHARINDEX(' ', Gspec) - 1) AS INT), ID
```

ID placement is the difference.

Here are the results:

| ID | Ring_Size | W_Size | Purity | F_Size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D46320 | 16 | 3.4 | 38 | 94 |
| F15555 | 10 | 10.1 | 4 | 81 |
| E64444 | 10 | 14.0 | 2 | 84.2 |
| B45555 | 10 | 14.01 | 4 | 83.1 |
| E64444 | 10 | 14.81 | 2 | 84.2 |
| E66744 | 10 | 15.1 | 2 | 87.1 |
| B45445 | 10 | 15.1 | 4 | 87.1 |
| B45475 | 10 | 15.1 | 4 | 87.1 |

This solves the purity ascending order but it splits up ID's as noted by the order of:

```
E64444,B45555,E64444
```

Is there a way to keep the purity ascending order, ID's together, all while still matching `W_Size`?

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for proper edits. I thought I had it correct this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have contradicting requirements in `w_size in ascending order while also keeping ID's together`, because the same ID may have both a smaller and a larger w_size than another ID. We can get around it by assigning a 'group' W_SIZE. I used MAX_W_SIZE here:

```
with MyTbl as (
select ID,  Ring_Size, W_Size,  Purity, F_Size, Max_W_Size=max(W_Size) over (partition by ID)
from (values 
 ('D46320', 16, 3.4     ,38 ,94   )
,('E64444', 10, 14.81   ,2  ,84.2 )
,('F15555', 10, 10.1    ,4  ,81   )
,('E64444', 10, 14.0    ,2  ,84.2 )
,('B45445', 10, 15.1    ,2  ,87.1 )
,('B45475', 10, 15.1    ,4  ,87.1 )
,('B45555', 10, 14.01   ,4  ,83.1 )
,('E66744', 10, 15.1    ,4  ,87.1 )
) T(ID, Ring_Size, W_Size,  Purity, F_Size)
)
select * from MyTbl 
order by 
  ring_size desc
, Max_W_Size
, ID
, W_Size
, Purity
```

I used your results as data; you can replace the VALUES part with your query.

Comment: So, if you have conflicting requirements, add an additional requirement grouping to override one of the conflicting requirements?

Comment: Yes, we want to assign a sortable group level attribute (in this case the ID is the group). When the group has variable values for the column to be sorted we want to choose just one of them; in this case we chose the highest w_size for ID.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the answer and even more for the explanation.